# Laptop won't charge when it's turned on, is hardware or software fault?

Tags: drivers, battery, asus-laptop

I have Asus s300ca, after some hit, I repaired my Laptop but I have a new problem when my laptop is on and sometime is off and open, it won,t charge (Actually it charge and don't and screen have some flash and battery status show charging and then discharging repeatedly). sometimes when the battery is full I could charge and use it but now I should turn off it charge it and use it. As you know Asus s300 have an inside battery. My operation system was win8 and now ubuntu 18.04 and I have this problem over both. Is it software or Hardware fault? How could I fix it?

Comment: Almost certainly hardware (99.99999999999999999999%)

Comment: I went to a repair shop and he tries with another charger and it worked!! I think I should buy a new adapter ?! which adapter do you recommend? I have seen some problems with the new brand adapters in this forum and a wide range of price! How could I found a suitable adapter?

Comment: Why did you not buy the one that worked in the shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault was in the cable of the adapter. I had the repair shop test my system with a known good cable, then I bought a new one - which appears to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly hardware (99.99999999999999999999%).

Take it back to the repair shop and ask them to fix it this time.

Hopefully your "repair" was under warranty.

Comment: Thank @Mawg, unfortunately, the guaranty is expired and as I said I had opened it already.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue, most likely the laptop is draining power faster then its being supplied - possibly due to a damaged battery cell.

Its conceivable, but a lot less likely that the circuitry negotiating charge speed is damaged.

Comment: Thank @davidgo,  can I bypass the battery and use power only? [it have an integrated buttery :() and is it a big deal or the cost of reparation is low?

Comment: Finding a reluable replacement battery is likely to be hard and of marginal value. You may well be able to disconnect the battery (as you say you have already opened the system - generally on laptops you just unplug it from the motherboard, but how difficult that operation is is make/model dependant).